# Expected value of relating random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

A gambling house has a game. Assume $Y$ be a random variable $(0 \lt Y \le 9)$ with probability density function $p(Y)$. And $T$ is a
random variable in $[9, \infty)$ such that $T = \dfrac{3}{T}+8$.
A random number $y$ is sampled from $T$, and the player
guesses a number $g \in [1, \infty)$ .

If $g \lt 10y$, then the player wins $-g − 5$
money from the gambling house (higher guesses win more money).

I am struggling to compute the expected profit for the player of this game. Any hints?

Comment: How does the player guess the number?. Does he follow a certain distribution? . does he follow the same distribution as Y to guess the number?. As it stands it seems like so

Comment: @Mr.Gandalf Sauron I think he follows the uniform distribution

Comment: The uniform distribution is bounded and defined on an interval (a,b) or [a,b]. I don't think you have uniform distribution over the semi infinite interval. You cannot make sense of the integral of a constant function from $1$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $g$ is a constant. Let $Z$ be the profit. By definition,

$$ Z = \begin{cases} g - 1 & \text{if} & Y > g \\
-1 & \text{if}& Y \leq g \end{cases}$$

Then

$$ \begin{align}
 E[Z] &= (g-1)\Pr\{Y > g\} - 1 \times \Pr\{Y \leq g\} \\
&= g\Pr\{Y > g\} - \left( \Pr\{Y > g\} + \Pr\{Y \leq g\}\right) \\
&= g\Pr\left\{X < \frac {1} {g}\right\} - 1 \\
&= g\int_0^{1/g}p(x)dx - 1
\end{align}$$

So that is how the answer related to $g$ and $p$

To find the optimal $g$, differentiate with respect to $g$,

$$ \begin{align}
 \frac {\partial} {\partial g} E[Z] &= \int_0^{1/g}p(x)dx
+ gp\left(\frac {1} {g} \right)\left(-\frac {1} {g^2}\right) \\
&= \int_0^{1/g}p(x)dx - \frac {1} {g} p\left(\frac {1} {g} \right)
\end{align}$$

We set this to be $0$ and solve the optimal $g$.

For example, when $p = 1$, corresponding to the uniform distribution,

$$ E[Z] = g\frac {1} {g} - 1 = 0$$

So the answer is independent of $g$ - any choice of $g$ will yield the same answer.